# How to list the content of my android device

Tags: android, shell, permissions, root, adb

I have an android G1 device as my developer phone. I have unlocked it and i can load image files to the phone using 'fastboot' command.

But when I open a 'adb shell' and try to list out the content of the directory /data/data using ls command, i get 'opendir failed, Permission denied'

```
$ adb shell
$ cd /data/data
$ ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
$ exit
$ adb remount
remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Can u please tell me how can i fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter `su` to become superuser.

Comment: i get a '$ adb shell
$ cd /data/data
$ su
su: permission denied'

Comment: Are you sure you rooted your phone?!

Comment: Can you tell me how to root HTC Incredible S?